# How do I use VB6 InStr IntStRev And Mid in c#

Tags: c#

I was using VB6 for a project later I switched to c# I have a function in my VB6 code I wanna use in my C# Project.

String.Substring maybe could do this.

Here is my VB6 Code.

```
position = InStr(1, strout, "4000072")

If position > 0 Then
    position2 = InStrRev(strout, "0000", position)
    strout = Mid$(strout, position2 - 512, 512)
End If
```

Comment: "String.Substring maybe could do this." - Yup. Along with `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf`.

Comment: An implementation of the scenario I have would be appreciated.

Comment: Just keep using these functions if you can figure out their replacement.  Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic, add using vb6 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings; to the top of the file and now you can write vb6.InStr, etc.

Comment: @HansPassant Am I the only one who wants to vomit when they think about code using that? Why learn C# at all then.

Comment: @Ashigore There's a *lot* of legacy code out there where it just isn't worth rewriting it in C#. Best to keep it in VB.NET imo.

Answer (score 1):

```
VB6: index = InStr( haystack, needle )
C# : index = haystack.IndexOf( needle );

VB6: index = InStrRev( haystack, needle )
C# : index = haystack.LastIndexOf( needle );

VB6: substring = Mid( largerString, start, length )
C# : substring = largerString.Substring( start, length );
```

In your case:

```
position = InStr(1, strout, "4000072")
If position > 0 Then
    position2 = InStrRev(strout, "0000", position)
    strout = Mid$(strout, position2 - 512, 512)
```

- The `1` in `InStr( 1, haystack, needle )` means "Start at the beginning", it's unnecessary so it can be ommitted. Note in .NET (both VB.NET and C#) string indexes start at `0` instead of `1`.
- The `$` at the end of `Mid$` is an archaic holdover from VB's very early days in the 1980s that isn't necessary even in VB6. Also your `If` is missing its `End If`.

So:

```
Int32 index400 = strout.IndexOf( "4000072" );
if( index400 > -1 ) {
    index000 = strout.LastIndexOf( "00000", index400 );

    Int32 start = Math.Max( index0000 - 512, 0 );
    Int32 length = Math.Min( 512, index0000.Length - start );  
    strout = strout.Substring( start, length );
}
```

Comment: Why index400 > -1 instead of index400 > 0
is this new logic?

Comment: Be aware that your C# equivalents are not identical, so don't just replace them blindly.  For example, Substring will throw if start+length is beyond the end of the string, while Mid will tolerate this.  If you want identical behaviour, you could use methods from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings` class (not available in .NET Core BTW), or, more likely, roll your own C# version.

Comment: @AmanAli `IndexOf` returns `-1` when the string **is not** found, and `0` when the string is found at the beginning (position 0). [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: @Joe I've modified my code to better mimic `Mid`'s behaviour.

Comment: @Dai The modified code have errors please check its every variable is named differently but not defined.